# how to select 3 popular sale product from database?

Tags: sql-server-2012

I need to select 3 most popular product from database, but I don't know how to select it. I using max(col_name), this give me only one item that is the most popular. That's not match my aim. I need the first most popular follow with the second most popular and third most popular product.

How to select that in sql server 2012?

Comment: I got it thank you for all your helpfullness.

Answer (score 3):

If you wanted to consider dealing with ties for first, second, and third, place, then you may use `DENSE_RANK` here:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT *, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY col_name DESC) dr
    FROM yourTable
    WHERE Boolean = 'False' AND Remark = 'Outstock'
) t
WHERE dr <= 3;
```

Comment: SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT *, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY CarID DESC) dr
    FROM tb_cardetail
) t
WHERE Boolean='Fasle' and Remark='Outstock' and dr <= 3;

Comment: this one select return empty

Comment: @Sai Because your query is wrong, and is not what I would have posted had I known you also had a `WHERE` clause.  See my updated answer.

Comment: again friends.  By this code SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT *, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY col_name DESC) dr
    FROM yourTable
    WHERE Boolean = 'False' AND Remark = 'Outstock'
) t
WHERE dr <= 3; how to get three min ? or three most unpopular

Comment: @Sai You should open a new question, and you should accept one of the two answers given here.

Answer (score 2):

You can sort the data in descending order and select the top 3 items with this query:

```
SELECT TOP 3 *
FROM table_name
ORDER BY col_name DESC
```

Comment: this statement seem empty selected because I have condition where.

Comment: if I using non condition this statement is correct.

Comment: @Sai: Add the WHERE condition before the ORDER BY line. (Between table_name and ORDER BY in my example.)

Comment: I got it. Thank you for your helpfullness