# How to get three min from table?

Tags: sql-server

I have a table `product`:

```
proID  Proname sellprice qty_istock   qty_outstock  remark
001    fish    20,000       5            20           Paid
002    tofu    5,000        2            32           paid
003    desert  10,000       10           50           paid
004    Salad   30,000       9            5            paid
005    wisky   12,000       100          2            paid
006    sprite  5,000        200          40           paid
```

My code looks like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT *, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY qty_outstock DESC) dr
    FROM product
) t
WHERE dr <= 3;
```

this code return top three popular product like:

```
PID  qty_outstock
003   50 
006   40
002   32
```

and now I need to change to three min like.

```
PID   qty_outstock
005     2
004     5
001    20
```

`My Question:` How to change it to get three min or three unpopular sale product from table?

Comment: change the `ORDER BY` from `DESC` to `ASC`

Comment: you mean the reverse order?

Comment: @Sai You should give credit to the people who [answered your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50173622/).

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I agree with you, really don't like these kind of users... I rewarded answers on that post :)

Comment: The `c#` tag is unnecessary.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen you got our back! ;)

Comment: I mean if I sell item (qty) 1 up to 20( it should be 20 rows). The given code return row 18 qty=18,row 19 qty=19 and row 20 qty =20. I now need to display in opposite or from min qty like return where qty =1,2,3.  min number at 1 max at 20.  sometime the qty not at 1, but here I just use it for example.

Comment: Some sample data would really help here.

Comment: Exactly, the nearly code is select min(qty) from table but here return only the number of min qty. That 's not match my result. I need to display more than one row with more than one column.

Comment: Just check my edit question.

Comment: SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT *, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY qty_outstock ASC) dr
    FROM product
) t
WHERE dr <= 3;

Answer (score 0):

The `ORDER BY` inside your `OVER` will determine how the `DENSE_RANK` generates the ranking.

So if you want it ordered by minimum firsts, just `ORDER BY qty_outstock ASC`.

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT *, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY qty_outstock ASC) dr
    FROM product
) t
WHERE dr <= 3;
```